# ExtJS4 editable grid getting selected row returns empty

Tags: javascript, extjs4, gridpanel

Trying to get the selected row index (and set another field value of the record afterwards) on a grid with CellEditing plugin, but **getSelection()** method returns an empty array. I have a listener for select event on the combobox, when that is changed I need to get the index of the edited row.

```
...
lazyRender: true,
listClass: 'x-combo-list-small',
listeners: {
    scope: this,
    select: function(field, value, options) {
        var selection = Ext.getCmp('lineItemsGrid').getSelectionModel().getSelection();                                            
        console.log(selection);
    }
}
...
```

I'm using ExtJS 4.0.2a release. I'm a newbie when it comes to ExtJS, so I might be missing something.

Here is JSFiddle file in cas you want to have a look.
http://jsfiddle.net/Z6b7a/8/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Oz

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `getSelection()` method, you can update the record directly from the edit event.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z6b7a/7/

I've updated the fiddle, and also here is the code to update the record after edit:

```
edit: function(editor, e, options) {
     e.record.set('light', 'Shade');
     //var selections = Ext.getCmp('lineItemsGrid').getSelectionModel().getSelection();
     //console.log(selections);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think it will work like this, but I should have been more clearer on my question. I want to do this when I user selects an item from the combobox, so I don't have access to e.record object. I have updated the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Z6b7a/8/) and will edit the original question to avoid misleading.